# Handwriting recognition windows 7

Tags: windows-7, handwriting

The handwriting recognition in windows 7 is quite awesome , i want to know if i could use it using some kind of API .

If not , is there any other alternative .

Comment: I agree that they are indeed awesome and often overlooked. They are, in fact, some of the very best available anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms702484%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the exposed APIs for "ink analysis".  They may work for you:

> There are four layers to the Ink Analysis library: Windows Forms, WPF, COM, and the base layer.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the handwriting tools in Windows 7 are an extension of those previously available in Microsoft Office and Windows XP.

They are usable by other applications though, knowing Microsoft, you will almost certainly end up needing a full MS tools set including Visual Studio.

Drat - @reuben has beaten me to an answer and given the appropriate link to MSDN.

UPDATE: If you want to look at an alternative, I recommend going to phatware.com - they've been in the handwriting space for a long time and have some interesting tools.